# How to match an enum variant in a match

Tags: rust

Is there a position for @ operator or some other solution that would bind the variable in a match arm to a variant type rather than to the entire enum? In the following example, all `bar`, `baz` and `qux` have types of Foo, rather than Foo::Bar, Foo::Baz, Foo::Qux and the sample fails to compile.

```rust
enum Foo {
   Bar(i32),
   Baz{s: String},
   Qux,
}

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo::Bar(42);

  match foo {
    bar @ Bar(..) => bar.0.to_string(),
    baz @ Baz{..} => baz.s,
    qux @ Qux => "".to_owned(),
  }
}
```

Comment: Enum variant types were proposed, but the RFC is [currently postponed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593#issuecomment-823429973) due to backlog.

Answer (score 3):

To reuse a variant [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/enumerations.html) you need to use enum tuple style and define external structure, it's a lot more used than enum struct:

```rust
struct Bar(i32);
struct Baz {
    s: String,
}

enum Foo {
    Bar(Bar),
    Baz(Baz),
    Qux,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Bar(Bar(42));

    let foo = match foo {
        Foo::Bar(bar) => bar.0.to_string(),
        Foo::Baz(baz) => baz.s,
        Foo::Qux => "".to_owned(),
    };
    
    assert_eq!(foo, "42");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though handy if they existed, there is no such thing as an enum variant type in Rust. All variants have the same type. Their contents, on the other hand, might carry values of different types.

For example, both `Foo::Bar(1)` and `Foo::Qux` have the *same type*, which is `Foo`. So you can't bind those values and treat them differently as they are of the same type.

The most “idiomatic” solution I can think of is to just grab what's inside of the specific enum variant you're currently matching on, like so:

```rs
fn main() {
  let foo = Foo::Bar(42);

  let my_string = match foo {
    Bar(bar) => bar.to_string(),
    Baz{ s } => s,
    Qux => "".to_owned(),
  };
}
```

Comment: I thought of Rust's enums are more like std::variant in C++ which basically is a discriminated union of other types. But it seems that this is not the case with Rust.

Comment: without `use Foo::*;` this shouldn't compile

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you're looking for is this?

```
enum Foo {
   Bar(i32),
   Baz{s: String},
   Qux,
}

fn main() {
  let foo = Foo::Bar(42);

  let s = match foo {
    Foo::Bar(bar) => bar.to_string(),
    Foo::Baz{s} => s,
    Foo::Qux => "".to_owned(),
  };
  
  dbg!(s);
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'd like to have a variable that would bind to a variant, not its fields.

Comment: Could you give a more full example in your original question which details your desired use case?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `use`:

```
enum Foo {
   Bar(i32),
   Baz{s: String},
   Qux,
}

fn main() {
  use Foo::*;
  let foo = Bar(42);

  let s = match foo {
    Bar(bar) => bar.to_string(),
    Baz{s} => s,
    Qux => "".to_owned(),
  };
}
```